# Equivalence testing of R and Rcpp code

Tags: r, rcpp

I have some C++ code to be integrated with R via Rcpp.

**My question is**:

Is there a function in Rcpp that gives logical output as to whether a block of C++ code is identical to a block of R code, perhaps something equivalent to identical() or all.equal(), which are both implemented in R?

In R, both identical() and all.equal() require two R objects for comparison. In my case, one object is R code and the other is C++ code.

I haven't been able to find anything in Rcpp documentation.

Comment: You are asking for a lot. Why don't you run both functions and compare results in a wide range of cases? If they all match, there's a good chance that your two  candidate functions are pretty similar (in function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have forest-and-trees problem here.

At the end of the day this really is just (in a boiled-down mock example):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double csCpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  return Rcpp::sum(x);
}

/*** R
csR <- function(x) sum(x)
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100)
all.equal(csR(x), csCpp(x))
*/
```

which, unsurprisingly, works out:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/soQ.cpp")

R> csR <- function(x) sum(x)

R> set.seed(42)

R> x <- rnorm(100)

R> all.equal(csR(x), csCpp(x))
[1] TRUE
R>
```

But as you cannot prove correctness for all inputs with just one input, you are back to designing suitable unit tests for different (representative) inputs.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to find some exmples in your Rcpp presentation slides, which are also helpful.